# How to import module like "UIKit" when using "swiftc" command to compile swift file?

Tags: swift, terminal

I create a swift file (test.swift):

```
import UIKit

func test() {
    let view = UIView()
    print(view)
}
```

Then run the command `swiftc test.swift` in terminal. It outputs

```
error: no such module 'UIKit'
```

How to import the 'UIKit' module?

Comment: Can you compile it once in Xcode and then have a view to the compiler logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link sdk and specify what target you building for:

```
swiftc input.swift 
    -o output.o 
    -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk 
    -target arm64-apple-ios12.0
```

Comment: works great, but now trying to execute the output I get `bad CPU type in executable`. if I'm  not mistaken it's because I build for arm64, but what to do if I want to test something using command line, which includes `UIKit`?